# What book is Milgrim reading in William Gibson's Spook Country?

Tags: william-gibson, blue-ant-trilogy, spook-country

Throughout William Gibson's *Spook Country* Milgrim is reading a book he found in the pocket of the coat he stole. Its a 1961 history of messianic medieval history.

Has anyone managed to identify the book?

Comment: You might want to do a little more research before you post. I googled '1961 history of messianic medieval history'. The [first result](http://www.san.beck.org/7-Bibliography.html) was a lengthy bibliography. `Ctrl-F` for '1961' found _[The Pursuit of the Millennium: Revolutionary Messianism in Medieval and Reformation Europe and its Bearing on Modern Totalitarian Movements](http://www.amazon.com/The-Pursuit-Millennium-Revolutionary-Totalitarian/dp/B0007I6TOQ)_ by Norman Cohn.

Comment: and have you read this book? given the clues in the text can you say its this one? I have been unable to source a copy of this book locally to check.

Comment: Also that book dates from 1957 although the 2nd edition came out in 1961.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I tweeted William Gibson [@GreatDismal](https://twitter.com/GreatDismal), including a link to this page. He has just answered "that one" (i.e. the one mentioned here above).

[Original tweet](https://twitter.com/desertnaut/status/280945674693005312):

> @GreatDismal What book is Milgrim reading in William Gibson's Spook Country?

[Response](https://twitter.com/GreatDismal/status/281043459186520066):

[image]

So it is indeed [*The Pursuit of the Millennium: Revolutionary Messianism in Medieval and Reformation Europe and its Bearing on Modern Totalitarian Movements*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0007I6TOQ) by Norman Cohn, [as found by sjl](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/28120/19561#comment-54775).

Comment: Thanks for the constructive answer. I had found the book title but hadn't been able to get a copy to read and didn't want to jump to conclusions.

Comment: Primary_source = awesome.

Comment: guess what I'm getting for Christmas